# I have Visual Studio 2010 running with the Crystal Reports plugin. What do I need to install on user machines to make the reports run?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'd have thought that there would be a simple answer to this, not requiring me to resort to StackOverflow, but apparently SAP are more interested in creating a maze than a website.

My question is, basically, what do I need to install on my users' machines/deploy with my project in order to get Crystal Reports reports to run, given that I'm creating the report forms using the VS2010 plugin?

Comment: +1 for, "SAP are more interested in creating a maze than a website"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install the runtime (32 bit or 64 bit) on their computers, which should have come with your initial download. If you can't find it or don't have it you can always get them from [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083).

Direct link http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/22083

They are shown on the page as:

Redist Installation (32 bit)

Redist Installation (64 bit)